# Is it fine to query Laravel Eloquent model inside rules method when validating request?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I need to perform a non standard validation in Laravel before I will insert something into DB. I need to query one row (particular field) before I will build an array with validation rules within `rules()` method.

I cannot access this value before I will send request so idea with passing it into hidden input and then submitting is not a solution in my case.

This field will be fetched thanks to another field that comes from the form. Then I will be able to create a rule like:

`'field_fetched_from_db' => 'not_in:foo,bar'`

next time it can be

`'field_fetched_from_db' => 'not_in:foo,baz'`

or

`'field_fetched_from_db' => 'not_in:baz,zaz'`

**Depending on the value of `field_fetched_from_db`, comma separated values will be a little bit different each time.**

I hope this makes sense. The question is, if making such Eloquent query inside `rules()` method is a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, done.

Within `rules()` method you can query Eloquent Model like so:

```
$data = $this->fooRepository->findOrFail(Request::input('some_id'));
$foo = $data->status_id; // from db
$bar = Request::input('another_id'); // from form
```

Next `$foo` and `$bar` have to take part in validation process:

`'status_is' => 'required|my_custom_validation_rule:' . $foo . ':' . $bar,`

Obviously `my_custom_validation_rule` has been defined in new `ServiceProvider`.

Then inside it, I'm simply exploding `$parameters` by `:` and do the rest of my work to finally return `true` if valid or `false` if not.